# asp.net variable passing

Tags: asp.net, variables

I am having an odd accuence when i am trying to get my page loaded value to place into a database after the user submits.

When the page loads i have this:

```
Public theProductName As String = ""
Dim theProductCategory As String = ""

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadProductName()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoadProductName()
    objConn = New MySqlConnection(product.strConnString)
    objConn.Open()

    strSQL = "SELECT id, name, category " & _
                "FROM product " & _
                "WHERE id = 4;"

    Try
        objCmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
        dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader()

        While dtReader.Read()
            theProductName = dtReader("name")
            theProductCategory = dtReader("category")
            btnSubmit.Text = "Add Item to " & theProductName
        End While

        dtReader.Close()
        dtReader = Nothing
        objConn.Close()
        objConn = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("LoadProductName: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When i check those values on startup of the page they have the correct values and even the submit button has the products name.

However, once i got to save it after pushing the button it has that same variable as nothing??

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

   Dim productName As String = theProductName.Replace(" ", "-")
   Dim imageName As String = productName & "\" & Trim(txtModel.Text) & ".jpg'"       
   Dim theCat as String = theProductCategory
End Sub
```

**productName** here is nothing as is **theCat**

What could i be overlooking?

Comment: What is 'theProductName'? It looks like a string - where is it declared/set?

Comment: @n8wrl: I have updated my OP with that information. I have **Public** for **theProductName** since i am using that within my html page **(<%=theProductName%>)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to persist your data with `ViewState`.because you post your data so you lost your old state

```
public string ProductName 
{
  get
  {
      if( Viewstate["ProductName"] == null)
      {
         return string.Empty;
      }
      return (string)Viewstate["ProductName"];
   } 
  set
  {
     Viewstate["ProductName"] = value;
  }
}
```

Set the value

```
ProductName = "your value";
```

Comment: How do i set the value from **theProductName** in that viewstate code above?

Comment: Just with this code : ProductName = "test"; i added the set section

Comment: I'am happy to help you StealthRT

Answer (score 1):

This is because you read the `theProductName` only when is not post back, on first load and then is not saved anywhere.

You can place the variable `theProductName`,  into the viewstate so you have it the same after the post back.

Example and more comments from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx